# For group $(\mathbb{C}^*, \times)$ , which are true; does it have finitely many finite subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

1. $\mathbb{C}^*$ is cyclic
2. $\mathbb{C}^*$ has finitely many finite subgroups
3. every proper subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^*$ is cyclic.

I have doubt in 2. I know 1 and 3 are false, but what about 2?

Comment: Related: [Finite subgroup of $\mathbb C^{\times}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1261321)

Comment: You have received a few downvotes and a close vote. You might improve your question by [adding context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). Probably not an ideal way - since they are a bit different from 2nd question which you are interested in - but probably explaining how you know that 1 and 3 are false might be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 is not true as for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: z^n=1\}$ forms a finite multiplicative subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^*$.

Comment: ... subgroup of order $n$, and so are all different.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for (2):

For a natural $\;n\;$ , think of $\;\xi_n:=e^{2\pi i/n}\;$

Answer (score -1):

we have the theorem: Let $G$ be a cycle group with generator $a$. if the order of $G$ is infinite, then $G$ isomorphism to $(Z,+)$ where $Z$ is integral numbers. if $G$ has finite order, then $G$ is isomorphism to $(Z_n,+)$. therefor $C^*$ isnot cyclic. 
there is infinte subgroups of finite order that form is $H=(\xi^{2\pi i/n} ); n\in N $. 
we have theroem: Every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic. we have $(Q^*,.) $ is subgroup in $(C^*,.)$ isnot cyclic.